# Use MongoDump to return on specific columns

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I know how to use MongoDump to dump the result of a specific query using the following command:

```
mongodump --username USER --password PASSWORD --db DBNAME --collection COLLECTION-NAME --query 
"{\"SOME-COLUMN\" : { \"$binary\" : \"SOME-BIN-DATA==\", \"$type\" : \"03\" } }"
```

But this will return back the entire document(s). is it possible to use MongoDump to return on a subset of the document? I want MongoDump to return only the ids of all collections matching the query, is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Projection in mongodump is not yet available.
[Reference](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-28).

mongoexport has such functionality using fields.

Comment: Thanks! that worked: 
mongoexport --username USER --password PWD --db DB --collection COLLECTION --query 
"{\"SOME-COLUMN\" : { \"$binary\" : \"SOME-VALUE\", \"$type\" : \"03\" } }" --fields "_id" --out c:\out.json